# search function is not working in master page in master detail app

Tags: javascript, sapui5

master view:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="com.abc.controller.Master" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic">
    <semantic:MasterPage id="page" title="{masterView>/title}" navButtonPress="onNavBack" showNavButton="true">
        <semantic:subHeader>
            <Bar id="headerBar">
                <contentMiddle>
                    <SearchField id="searchField" showRefreshButton="{= !${device>/support/touch} }" tooltip="{i18n>masterSearchTooltip}" width="100%"
                        search="onSearch" liveChange="onSearch"></SearchField>
                </contentMiddle>
            </Bar>
        </semantic:subHeader>
        <semantic:content>
            <PullToRefresh id="pullToRefresh" visible="{device>/support/touch}" refresh="onRefresh"/>
            <List id="list"
                items="{ path: '/MaterialDocReservationSet', sorter: { path: 'MBLNR', descending: false }, groupHeaderFactory: '.createGroupHeader' }"
                busyIndicatorDelay="{masterView>/delay}" noDataText="{masterView>/noDataText}"
                mode="{= ${device>/system/phone} ? 'None' : 'SingleSelectMaster'}" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true"
                updateFinished="onUpdateFinished" selectionChange="onSelectionChange">
                <infoToolbar>
                    <Toolbar active="true" id="filterBar" visible="{masterView>/isFilterBarVisible}" press="onOpenViewSettings">
                        <Title id="filterBarLabel" text="{masterView>/filterBarLabel}"/>
                    </Toolbar>
                </infoToolbar>
                <items>
                    <ObjectListItem id="listItem" type="{= ${device>/system/phone} ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}" press="onSelectionChange" title="{MBLNR}"
                        number="{ path: 'RSNUM' }">
                        <secondStatus>
                            <ObjectStatus text="{MJAHR}" visible="true"/>
                        </secondStatus>
                    </ObjectListItem>
                </items>
            </List>
        </semantic:content>
    </semantic:MasterPage>
</mvc:View>
```

Master Controller :

```
/*global history */
sap.ui.define([
    "com/abc/controller/BaseController",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "sap/ui/core/routing/History",
    "sap/ui/model/Filter",
    "sap/ui/model/FilterOperator",
    "sap/m/GroupHeaderListItem",
    "sap/ui/Device",
    "com/abc/model/formatter"
], function(BaseController, JSONModel, History, Filter, FilterOperator, GroupHeaderListItem, Device, formatter) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("com.abc.controller.Master", {

        formatter: formatter,

        /* =========================================================== */
        /* lifecycle methods                                           */
        /* =========================================================== */

        /**
         * Called when the master list controller is instantiated. It sets up the event handling for the master/detail communication and other lifecycle tasks.
         * @public
         */
        onInit: function() {
            // Control state model
            var oList = this.byId("list"),
                oViewModel = this._createViewModel(),

                iOriginalBusyDelay = oList.getBusyIndicatorDelay();

            this._oList = oList;
            // keeps the filter and search state
            this._oListFilterState = {
                aFilter: [],
                aSearch: []
            };

            this.setModel(oViewModel, "masterView");

            oList.attachEventOnce("updateFinished", function() {
                // Restore original busy indicator delay for the list
                oViewModel.setProperty("/delay", iOriginalBusyDelay);
            });

            this.getView().addEventDelegate({
                onBeforeFirstShow: function() {
                    this.getOwnerComponent().oListSelector.setBoundMasterList(oList);
                }.bind(this)
            });

            this.getRouter().getRoute("master").attachPatternMatched(this._onMasterMatched, this);
            this.getRouter().attachBypassed(this.onBypassed, this);
        },

        onUpdateFinished: function(oEvent) {
            // update the master list object counter after new data is loaded
            this._updateListItemCount(oEvent.getParameter("total"));
            // hide pull to refresh if necessary
            this.byId("pullToRefresh").hide();
        },

        onSearch: function(oEvt) {

            // add filter for search
            var aFilter = [];
            var sQuery = oEvt.getSource().getValue();
            if (sQuery && sQuery.length > 0) {
                var filter = new Filter("MBLNR", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery);
                aFilter.push(filter);
            }

            // update list binding
            var list = this.byId("list");
            var binding = list.getBinding("items");
            binding.filter(aFilter, "Application");
        },

        onRefresh: function() {
            this._oList.getBinding("items").refresh();
        },

        onSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {

            this._showDetail(oEvent.getParameter("listItem") || oEvent.getSource());
        },

        /**
         * Event handler for the bypassed event, which is fired when no routing pattern matched.
         * If there was an object selected in the master list, that selection is removed.
         * @public
         */
        onBypassed: function() {
            this._oList.removeSelections(true);
        },

        createGroupHeader: function(oGroup) {
            return new GroupHeaderListItem({
                title: oGroup.text,
                upperCase: false
            });
        },

        onNavBack: function() {
            var sPreviousHash = History.getInstance().getPreviousHash(),
                oCrossAppNavigator = sap.ushell.Container.getService("CrossApplicationNavigation");

            if (sPreviousHash !== undefined || !oCrossAppNavigator.isInitialNavigation()) {
                history.go(-1);
            } else {
                oCrossAppNavigator.toExternal({
                    target: {
                        shellHash: "#Shell-home"
                    }
                });
            }
        },

        /* =========================================================== */
        /* begin: internal methods                                     */
        /* =========================================================== */

        _createViewModel: function() {
            return new JSONModel({
                isFilterBarVisible: false,
                filterBarLabel: "",
                delay: 0,
                title: this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterTitleCount", [0]),
                noDataText: this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterListNoDataText"),
                sortBy: "RSNUM",
                groupBy: "None"
            });
        },

        _onMasterMatched: function() {
            debugger;
            this.getOwnerComponent().oListSelector.oWhenListLoadingIsDone.then(
                function(mParams) {
                    if (mParams.list.getMode() === "None") {
                        return;
                    }
                    var sObjectId = mParams.firstListitem.getBindingContext().getProperty("MBLNR");
                    var sObjectId1 = mParams.firstListitem.getBindingContext().getProperty("RSNUM");
                    this.getRouter().navTo("object", {
                        objectId: sObjectId,
                        objectId1: sObjectId1
                    }, true);
                }.bind(this),
                function(mParams) {
                    if (mParams.error) {
                        return;
                    }
                    this.getRouter().getTargets().display("detailNoObjectsAvailable");
                }.bind(this)
            );
        },

        _showDetail: function(oItem) {
            var bReplace = !Device.system.phone;
            this.getRouter().navTo("object", {
                objectId: oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("MBLNR"),
                objectId1: oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("RSNUM")
            }, bReplace);
        },

        _updateListItemCount: function(iTotalItems) {
            var sTitle;
            // only update the counter if the length is final
            if (this._oList.getBinding("items").isLengthFinal()) {
                sTitle = this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterTitleCount", [iTotalItems]);
                this.getModel("masterView").setProperty("/title", sTitle);
            }
        },

        _applyFilterSearch: function() {
            var aFilters = this._oListFilterState.aSearch.concat(this._oListFilterState.aFilter),
                oViewModel = this.getModel("masterView");
            this._oList.getBinding("items").filter(aFilters, "Application");
            // changes the noDataText of the list in case there are no filter results
            if (aFilters.length !== 0) {
                oViewModel.setProperty("/noDataText", this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterListNoDataWithFilterOrSearchText"));
            } else if (this._oListFilterState.aSearch.length > 0) {
                // only reset the no data text to default when no new search was triggered
                oViewModel.setProperty("/noDataText", this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterListNoDataText"));
            }
        },

        _applyGroupSort: function(aSorters) {
            this._oList.getBinding("items").sort(aSorters);
        },

        _updateFilterBar: function(sFilterBarText) {
            var oViewModel = this.getModel("masterView");
            oViewModel.setProperty("/isFilterBarVisible", (this._oListFilterState.aFilter.length > 0));
            oViewModel.setProperty("/filterBarLabel", this.getResourceBundle().getText("masterFilterBarText", [sFilterBarText]));
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: @OP, when posting one hundred lines of code, explaining your problem and your code a little bit could really be better.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? try removing irrelevant code?

Comment: You should omit „Application“ parameter in onSearch function. But that is not the problem. I don’t see a problem in your onSearch function. What error are you getting? This may well be a backend problem. First, you should check what request is sent out to server once you start typing in your search field

Comment: Hi i am not getting any error,but it does not search even not giving message NO Data.

Comment: if this is not an already existing app you should do it over anyways, since the master detail layout is depricated and replaced with flexible column layout, check the fiori designguidelines pls

Comment: @user10378010 if you get no response whatsoever, try debugging! does it call your onSearch function at all?? if it does, it should trigger a backend request after you call .filter()

Comment: Check the oData call made when you perform search and see what is the backend returning ?

Answer (score -1):

Hope below code will work for you..

```
onSearch: function (oEvent) {        
    var aFilters = [];// add filters for search
    var sQuery = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
    if (sQuery && sQuery.length > 0) {
        var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("MBLNR", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery);
        aFilters = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilter], false);
    }
    var oList = this.getView().byId("list");// update list binding
    var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
    oBinding.filter(aFilters, "Application");
}
```

Comment: you dont need to OR a single filter! apart from that, there is no difference to the original

Comment: There is difference from the original, If you observe `aFilter.push(filter);` in the original one and `aFilters = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oFilter], false);`. Hope you got it?

Comment: @inzio I did notice that => you combine the oFilter with OR to a new filter. as I said, there is no point in doing that. Apart from that, ListBinding.filter wants an ARRAY of filters, you give the function just one filter

Comment: Hi its still not working.can you suggest me will it hit the oData call every time we type anything in search field in master page search field.what i can see as of now is that when i type anything in search field there is no response.